# How to pass the data from vue component to another one?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I should write an app with electron js and vue which you should navigate to folder that contain photos then the other component show all the photos one by one and ask user to rate them out of 10 and after finishing all the photos , it ask the user's name and write name of the user and his rating to each photo in a csv file. i've wroten the file explorer component but i don't know how to pass photos of selected directory to other component here is my code:

```
//FileBrowser.vue
<script>
import fs from 'fs'
import pathModule from 'path'
import { app } from '@electron/remote'
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import emitter from '@/eventBus'

import FilesViewer from './FilesViewer'
const formatSize = size => {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.log(size) / Math.log(1024))
  return (
    (size / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(2) * 1 +
    ' ' +
    ['B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'][i]
  )
}

export default {
  name: 'FileBrowser',
  components: { FilesViewer },
  setup() {

    const path = ref(app.getAppPath())
    emitter.emit('select-folder',this,path)
    const files = computed(() => {
      const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(path.value)
      return fileNames
        .map(file => {
          const stats = fs.statSync(pathModule.join(path.value, file))
          return {
            name: file,
            size: stats.isFile() ? formatSize(stats.size ?? 0) : null,
            directory: stats.isDirectory()
          }
        })
        .sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.directory === b.directory) {
            return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
          }
          return a.directory ? -1 : 1
        })
    })

    const back = () => {
      path.value = pathModule.dirname(path.value)
    }
    const open = folder => {
      path.value = pathModule.join(path.value, folder)
    }

    const searchString = ref('')
    
    const filteredFiles = computed(() => {
      return searchString.value
        ? files.value.filter(s => s.name.startsWith(searchString.value))
        : files.value
        
    })
    
    return {
      path,

      open,
      back,

      files,
      searchString,
      filteredFiles
    }
  }
}


</script>

<template>
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
          <h5 @change="select-folder">{{ path }}</h5>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <FilesViewer
      :files="filteredFiles"
      :nested="nested"
      @back="back"
      @folderclick="open($event.name)"
    />
      </ul>
  </nav>
</template>

<style scoped>
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}
#sidebar {
  min-width: 300px;
max-width: 300px;
min-height: 100vh;
background: #1d1919;
color: #fff;
}

</style>
```

```
//FileViewer.vue
<script>
import IconFile from './IconFile'
import IconFolder from './IconFolder'
import IconFolderOpen from './IconFolderOpen'

export default {
  name:'FileViewer',
  props: {
    files: { type: Array, default: () => [] }
  },
  components: { IconFile, IconFolder, IconFolderOpen },
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    const onFileClick = file => {
      if (file.directory) emit('folderclick', file)
    }
    return { onFileClick }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="clickable" @click="$emit('back')">
        <td class="icon-row">
          <IconFolderOpen class="icon-folder" />
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr
        v-for="file in files"
        :key="file.name"
        :class="{ clickable: file.directory }"
        @click="onFileClick(file)"
      >
        <td class="icon-row">
          <IconFolder v-if="file.directory" class="icon-folder" />
          <IconFile v-else class="icon-file" />
        </td>
        <td>{{ file.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <span class="float-end">{{ file.size }}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<style scoped>


.icon-row {
  width: 2em;
}
.icon-folder {
  width: 1em;
  
}
.icon-file {
  width: 0.75em;

}
td{
  color: #fff;
}
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f8b739;
}
</style>
```

```
//App.vue

<script>
import FileBrowser from './components/FileBrowser.vue'
import emitter from './eventBus';
emitter.on('select-folder',val=>{
  console.log(val);
})
export default{
  name:'App',
  components:{FileBrowser}
}

</script>

<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <FileBrowser/>
 
</div>
</template>

<style>
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

</style>
```

Comment: [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).  A store offer a common storage location all components can read and write from.